# How to calculate the percentage of specific elements in a vector?

Tags: r, vector

For example, I have a vector of numbers:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

What's a simple way that I can have R count the percentage of numbers that are less than 5?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be to convert to a logical vector and then do the mean

```
mean(x < 5)
#[1] 0.3636364
```

---

Other option is to convert to a frequency table and then get the proportion with `prop.table`

```
prop.table(table(x < 5))[2]
#    TRUE 
#0.3636364
```